# 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims on Minikube

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, minikube, persistent-volumes

I'm trying to use kubernetes with a spring boot application and use mysql. But i found this error on minikube dashboard:

```
0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.Back-off restarting failed container
```

A secret file is created for boath user and admin and a configMap file also to map the spring boot image to the service of mysql.
Mysql deployement file is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql  # DNS name
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:       # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    app: mysql
    tier: database
  clusterIP: None  # We Use DNS, Thus ClusterIP is not relevant
---
# Define a 'Persistent Volume Claim'(PVC) for Mysql Storage, dynamically provisioned by cluster
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim # name of PVC essential for identifying the storage data
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce   #This specifies the mode of the claim that we are trying to create.
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi    #This will tell kubernetes about the amount of space we are trying to claim.
---
# Configure 'Deployment' of mysql server
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
    tier: database
spec:
  selector: # mysql Pod Should contain same labels
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
      tier: database
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels: # Must match 'Service' and 'Deployment' selectors
        app: mysql
        tier: database
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:latest # image from docker-hub
          args:
            - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found" # Workaround for https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186
          name: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD # Setting Root Password of mysql From a 'Secret'
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-admin # Name of the 'Secret'
                  key: password   # 'key' inside the Secret which contains required 'value'
            - name: MYSQL_USER # Setting USER username on mysql From a 'Secret'
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-user
                  key: username
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD # Setting USER Password on mysql From a 'Secret'
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-user
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_DATABASE # Setting Database Name from a 'ConfigMap'
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: db-config
                  key: name
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              name: mysql
          volumeMounts:        # Mounting volume obtained from Persistent Volume Claim
            - name: mysql-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql #This is the path in the container on which the mounting will take place.
      volumes:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage # Obtaining 'volume' from PVC
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

I'm new with kubernetes and I can't find solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to create a PV to satisfy the PVC. If you apply the below PV it should work.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Please note below points

1. Usage of `hostPath` is not recommended in production
2. `capacity` of PV and PVC needs to match
3. `accessModes` of PV and PVC needs to match

Answer (score 4):

To use a `PersistentVolumeClaim` you need some kind of underlying storage system. The cloud providers provides dynamic provisioning of volumes when you create PVCs using their *storage class*. This does not come out of the box with Minikube.

You can follow [Configure a Pod to Use a PersistentVolume for Storage](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/) for how to setup `PersistentVolume` for Minikube so that your application can use a `PersistentVolumeClaim`.

Answer (score 4):

1.Run `minikube addons list` to see if the `storage-provisioner` is enabled:

```
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
|         ADDON NAME          | PROFILE  |    STATUS    |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
| dashboard                   | minikube | disabled     |
| default-storageclass        | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| efk                         | minikube | disabled     |
| freshpod                    | minikube | disabled     |
| gvisor                      | minikube | disabled     |
| helm-tiller                 | minikube | disabled     |
| ingress                     | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| ingress-dns                 | minikube | disabled     |
| istio                       | minikube | disabled     |
| istio-provisioner           | minikube | disabled     |
| logviewer                   | minikube | disabled     |
| metrics-server              | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-driver-installer     | minikube | disabled     |
| nvidia-gpu-device-plugin    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry                    | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-aliases            | minikube | disabled     |
| registry-creds              | minikube | disabled     |
| storage-provisioner         | minikube | enabled ✅   |
| storage-provisioner-gluster | minikube | disabled     |
|-----------------------------|----------|--------------|
```

2. If it's not, enable it with `minikube addons enable storage-provisioner`.

See [Persistent Volumes](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/)