# Why does pod status remain 'PENDING'?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, devops

Here is the output I am getting:

```
    [root@ip-10-0-3-103 ec2-user]# kubectl get pod --namespace=migration
    NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    clear-nginx-deployment-cc77649fb-j8mzj        0/1     Pending   0          118m
    clear-nginx-deployment-temp-cc77649fb-hxst2   0/1     Pending   0          41s
```

Could not understand the message shown in json:

```
*"status": 
{
        "conditions": [
            {
                "message": "0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.",

                "reason": "Unschedulable",
                "status": "False",
                "type": "PodScheduled"
            }
        ],
        "phase": "Pending",
        "qosClass": "BestEffort"
}*
```

If you could please help to get through this.
The earlier question on stackoverflow doesn't answer my query as my message output is different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims on Minikube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970511/1-pod-has-unbound-immediate-persistentvolumeclaims-on-minikube)

Comment: you will also need to post your k8s.yaml for deploying this pod. It looks like you are trying to mount a volume that has not been created.

Comment: Hi @JoshBeauregard,  I have verified that required pv, and pvc is been deployed before the deployment is posted (and ultimately the pods).

Comment: okay, is your cluster a in an multi region environment? could it be that the volume is attached to a worker that your pod cant mount due to a data center restriction? I have had this happen in EKS.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that your Pods have been instructed to claim storage, however, in your case there is storage available.
Check your Pods with `kubectl get pods <pod-name> -o yaml` and look at the exact yaml that has been applied to the cluster. In there you should be able to see that the Pod is trying to claim a PersistentVolume (PV).

To quickly create a PV backed by a `hostPath` apply the following yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: stackoverflow-hostpath
  namespace: migration
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Kubernetes will exponentially try to schedule the Pod again; to speed things up delete one of your pods (`kubectl delete pods <pod-name>`) to reschedule it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @F1ko,
But let me tell you, I'm actually posting a deployment, not the pod. The pod is been created as it is the part of a replicaset inside deployment.
Now, to make sure respected pv and pvc are available for future pods to claim, I am creating a pv and a pv claim just before the deployment is posted. 

Suppose, if I'm talking about a pv named 'site-data' and a pvc named 'demo-pv-claim' in the deployment yaml, so a pv named 'site-data' and a pvc named 'demo-pv-claim' will already be present for the further processes.
Please ask if anything needed to get more on it.

Comment: @kkpareek : due to the two hash values in its name it is totally clear that it is a deployment, however, all the important information is within the pod manifest.
Without having too much information regarding the pod, pv and pvc you are talking about this is a "blind" debugging session. From the top of my head there are at least 4 possible reasons why this might occur to you, without further information it is hard to give a precise answer as to why this is happening to you. Are you using a CSI? Are you in a cloud? What do your manifests look like?